# Could not instantiate bean class annotationsessionfactorybean

Tags: spring, hibernate

*Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sf' defined in class path resource [resouce/springXML.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration
*
* PLEASE HELP ME*

> ERROR

```
5.3.1.Final
: 3.2 cr4
Jan 19, 2020 6:44:42 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@ad9418: startup date [Sun Jan 19 18:44:42 IST 2020]; root of context hierarchy
Jan 19, 2020 6:44:42 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [resouce/springXML.xml]
Jan 19, 2020 6:44:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@18e2867: defining beans [bds,sf,ht,dao]; root of factory hierarchy
Jan 19, 2020 6:44:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@18e2867: defining beans [bds,sf,ht,dao]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sf' defined in class path resource [resouce/springXML.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:946)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:892)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at test.client.main(client.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:72)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.<init>(AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
```

> XML file

````
            "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
   <bean id="bds" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
    <property name="username" value="rayudu"/>
    <property name="password" value="oracle10g"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="15"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="5000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sf" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="bds"/>
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
             <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
     </property>
     <property name="annotatedClasses">
         <list>
            <value>model.Student</value>
         </list>
     </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ht" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sf"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dao" class="dap.StudentDAOImp">
    <property name="ht" ref="ht"/>
    </bean> 
</beans>```

*please help me*
````

Comment: If you look carefully, you see : `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration
`... Could you please show your POM.xml. And how do you run your application ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error: `Error creating bean with name 'sf' defined in class path resource [resouce/springXML.xml]` says spring is not able create bean with name `'sf'` defined in `springXML.xml`.

And the subsequent error :

`Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration`

says the class is not present. It could be that you have not added the required hibernate dependency  or the application is not built correctly.

Please check the dependency and try rebuilding the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` in place of `org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration`.

Comment: _i tried all what you are said but it's again showing_